# ts2339 error: how to use typescript mixin in vuejs project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins, vue-mixin

i recently converted my vuejs to typescript base, but now i have problem with using mixin in typescript.
i used two types of mixin, but none worked for me and it shows error ts2339, and i couldnt found the solution on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage:
[image]
first one:

```
//mixin.ts
import {ViewState} from "@/types";
import {mocked_view_state} from "@/api/mock/profile.device.group.mock";

export const ProfileDeviceGroup = {
  methods: {
    resetViewState(): ViewState {
      return mocked_view_state;
    }
  }
};
```

second one:

```
//mixin.ts
import Vue from "vue";
import {ViewState} from "@/types";
import {mocked_view_state} from "@/api/mock/profile.device.group.mock";

const ProfileDeviceGroup = Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    resetViewState(): ViewState {
      return mocked_view_state;
    },

  }
});
export default ProfileDeviceGroup;
```

so, is there any way to fix this problem?

..............

**Update:**

..............

after using vue-typed-mixins, the problem has been solved, but another problem exposes as you can see in below picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this issue
https://github.com/ktsn/vue-typed-mixins/issues/4
 which i created in vue-typed-mixins's github, it is a not-fixed issue which the author believes webstorm and Vuetr plugin should fix, and its not related to vue-typed-mixins. 
however i think the problem still is related to vue-typed-mixins plugin, but i hope the problem will be fixed soon and should thank the author of vue-typed-mixins team, and webstorm team and Vuetr.

for those who (like myself) want to keep going with vue+typescript, there seems to be a better way to pass these problems, which is **vue2-composition-api**, which some teams has been using and told me it was ok with typescript and has no problem since there is no need to use mixin anymore.
[is vuejs2.x composition api fully compatibile with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873235/is-vuejs2-x-composition-api-fully-compatibile-with-typescript)

i hope it work...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package like [vue-typed-mixins](https://github.com/ktsn/vue-typed-mixins) or migrate to the [Vue class component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) pattern and use `implements`.

```js
@Component
export default class ComponentWithMixins extends Vue implements MyMixin {}
```

If you're using `vue-property-decorator`, that has built-in support for mixins as well:

```js
@Component
export default class ComponentWithMixins extends mixins(MyMixin) {}
```

Comment: it fixed the problem, but exposes another, which shows me unresolved functions(the function which is used in template are now unresolved )

Comment: Want to open up a new issue with code snippets? I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Where is `onPageChange` being defined?

Comment: in method:{}  option at the component it self.

Comment: Have you updated your tsconfig file? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Recommended-Configuration

Comment: It also may be that it's unable to resolve the method because it doesn't exist as a class method as it would if you used the `vue-class-component` pattern. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components

Comment: yes i checked it but the problem is still present. this is a reprex:
https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon/reprex-vue-typed-mixins-unresolved-function-error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant but I found out by looking at the vue-router type definition file that you can manually add all necessary types for your mixin globally by extending the ComponentCustomProperties interface within the @vue/runtime-core module.

You should be able to include all type definitions by adding this to your mixin.ts file:

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        resetViewState: () => ViewState;
    }
}
```

However I've only tested this in vscode using vue3 with regular single-file-componants and sometimes it was necessary to reload the current vscode window to apply all type changes to the runtime-core.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a technique that allows you to get typings for mixins in a Vue-TypeScript project with vue-property-decorator:

```js
// your-mixin.ts
import Vue from "vue"
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator"

@Component
export default class YourMixin extends Vue {
    // make all your properties and methods public.
    // any properties that you don't want changing, should be marked as readonly
    public readonly test: string = "test"

    public get sampleNumber(): number {
       return 1
    }

    public sampleMethod(): void {
        
    }
}
```

```
// your-component.vue
import { Component, Mixins } from "vue-property-decorator"
import YourMixin from "@/mixins/YourMixin"

@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Mixins(YourMixin) {
    // in Components that have one mixin, you don't need to do anything else, 
    // but if it has more than one Mixin, reimplement the Mixin 
    // properties without instantiating them:

    public test!: string
    public sampleMethod!: CallableFunction

    // sometimes TypeScript complains if you set a method's type as (arg: string) => void
    // because for some reason it thinks you're gonna use the arg even though
    // we are just defining a type, so just use the generic CallableFunction instead
}
```