# is vuejs2.x composition api fully compatibile with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components, vue-composition-api

Recently i migrated our vue.js2.x project to typescript, and based on evan-you's comment in this issue:

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/17#issuecomment-494242121

The Class API proposal is being dropped. so i'm using regular option based version of vue.js which it faced me with alot of type problems.

I want to know is vuejs2.x composition api fully compatibile with typescript? and should i use it to solve all the problem? 
what is the best practice to do here in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what "fully compatible with TypeScript" means. But you can definitely use TypeScript with the Vue composition API, and TypeScript helps to improve the code and the developer experience.

Here is an example using the [composition plugin with Vue 2](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api):

```
import { computed, createComponent, reactive } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default createComponent({
  name: "Hello",

  template: `<p>{{ state.message }}</p>`,

  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },

  setup(props, context) {
    const state = reactive({
      message: computed(() => `Hello, ${props.name}!`)
    });
    return {
      state
    };
  }
});
```

All the above code is well typed. The composition API (here: `createComponent`, `reactive`, `computed`) is provided with correct types. Notice that with the composition API, we don't need to use `this` anymore.

Comment: i mean when, you using vue.sj with type script,  then using mixins and alot of other things, have detection problem... like this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828104/ts2339-error-how-to-use-typescript-mixin-in-vuejs-project".
does compostion api have such problems?

Comment: @SeyyedKhandon The Composition API aims to replace mixins. You don't need mixins if you use the composition API, because there is nothing to mix anymore. I quote the [documentation](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/#logic-extraction-and-reuse): _"Similar logic reuse can also be achieved using existing patterns such as mixins, higher-order components or renderless components (via scoped slots). […]  The high level idea is that each of these patterns has respective drawbacks when compared to composition functions […]"_

Comment: If your question is: "Is TypeScript a relevant choice for the whole code of an application using the Composition API of Vue.js?"… In our company, we finished last month migrating the codebase (100% TypeScript) of our current projects from the old Vue class API to the composition API. The new code is just better, including typing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vue.js is compatible with TypeScript as the Vue CLI provides built-in TypeScript tooling support. It just needs to be installed via `npm` or `yarn`, as stated [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Development-Tooling), hereby it won't need any additional tooling to use TS with Vue.
There are also some explanations about [recommended configuration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Recommended-Configuration) and [basic usage](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage) included in the given links.

Comment: vuejs by default has problems with types in typescript as noted by core vuejs team and if you had any exprience, you will face with problems like mixins. so because of that, i asked a question  about the compostion api, which i think your answer is not related to the question...